# Full wave rectifier capacitance calculation for battery charger

Tags: power-supply

To make a 60A, 220V DC battery charger, how do I calculate output capacitance value to avoid ripple voltage?

I know the C = I*dt/dV formula but is it the same for a capacitive load?

Edit:

I don't want to trickle charge the battery, so I thought I would use a capacitor in parallel to the load (which is battery itself,) so that I can maintain the voltage output at my desired value using a thyristor controlled bridge. This capacitor must deliver current for charging battery without ripple, so I was wondering if I can use same formula or not.

Does this formula apply only for resistive loads?

Comment: In what way is your battery charger a 'capacitive load'?

Comment: A battery that charges for many  minutes with 60A of current, ALWAYS avoids ripple voltage.

Comment: You need "only" a resistor for limiting peak current ...

Comment: The battery is the massive capacitance load in xxx kilofarads

Comment: @BruceAbbott : I consider Battery as Capacitive load. Isn't it right?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 : I agree. But I donot want to "trickle charge" the battery. So I thought I would use a capacitor in parallel to load(which is battery itself), so that I can maintain the voltage output at my desired value using thyristor controlled bridge.

Comment: You said you want no ripple, so the capacitance must be infinite. For any practical purpose, the battery is the capacitor.

Comment: Vish. You need a better model of a battery with ESR's and C's to model ripple then use 3ph alternator model with linear current modulation to get constant voltage, or is this a Supercharge goal from single phase. Got specs?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 : Thanks for hint. I realize from all comments that this question is not a simple yes/no question. It needs more discussion which better asked in forum. So I would continue the topic eda or aac forum. Thanks all for help.

Comment: Step back and define problem, opportunity, targets in measurable specs. Then define assumptions, validate and then ask better question. Otherwise it is a vague discussion

Answer (score 1):

There are simple means, but with some issues.
As already stated, **no capacitor need**.
First try, with a simple resistor (no transformer used). What happens?
Only PULSED sinusoidal current. NB: one can use also a tri-phased transformer (lower ripple).
The resistor limits current. See power in it (avg, RMS).

[image]

[image]

One can use also an inductor (case 1 ohm, 10 mH).

[image]

Or a lower resistor (case 0.1 ohm, 10 mH)

[image]

NB: some practical problems to solve.
Power in the resistor (200 W?), current in the inductor (10 mH with 60A?).
Use of some voltage points in the output transformer secondary or auto-transformer.
Use of "electronic transformer". As this one ... To be tested.

[image]